# How to use DBContext to save data permanently in my local sql DB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2019, localdb

I'm trying to understand why my data is not saved in my local SQL db when my app is closed.
I'm running a simple console application, which is connected to an SQL server.

Here is my connection string:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=SwagAiDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

I've created the following class:

```
    public partial class SwagAiDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SwagAiDbContext()
        {
        }

        public SwagAiDbContext(DbContextOptions<SwagAiDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<IndustrySection> IndustrySection { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SwagAiDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.CompanyName).IsRequired();

                entity.Property(e => e.Url).IsRequired();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<IndustrySection>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.IndustryCode)
                    .HasName("PK_IndustryCode");

                entity.Property(e => e.IndustryCode).ValueGeneratedNever();
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
```

On my code, I'm calling to the following methods just as an example ('Company' is a table on my DB). I would like later on to fill my DB with actual data that is NOT deleted when I'm closing my app.

```
using (var db = new SwagAiDbContext())
{
    db.Company.Add(new Company{ [... adding the required parameters here...] });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The data is added to the DB. Everything looks fine. But when I re-launch my app the DB is empty. All the tables exist, but no data is found.

Please help me.

Comment: Removed Visual-c++ tag: this has nothing to do with C++

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the constructor of your Context?

Comment: first question: are you reaching the database? Second Question: in that case, what query are you executing (everything, including parameters)? Third question: are you getting an error?

Comment: Probably problem can be on startup, not in dbcontext. Or on closing of  application.

Comment: Thanks guys, for your quick responses. I've added the complete code for my class.I can reach the DB. I can see the new records in the debugger and there is no error.

Comment: Have you checked this document? [Code First to a New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database).

Comment: @KyleWang I'm looking into it right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check if you are using DropCreateDatabaseAlways database initializer option.

**EDIT**:
Another option to try:
move your connection string to app config

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SwagAiDbContext"  
    connectionString="data source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=SwagAiDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

and rewrite dbcontext like this:

```
    public SwagAiDbContext()
        : base("name=SwagAiDbContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<IndustrySection> IndustrySection { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.CompanyName).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.Url).IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IndustrySection>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.IndustryCode)
                .HasName("PK_IndustryCode");

            entity.Property(e => e.IndustryCode).ValueGeneratedNever();
        });

    }
```

Comment: Is this option should appear in the constructor? I'm using an empty one

Comment: @MayaStern yes, in the constructor and right, you are using an empty one. Check the edit pls

Comment: I tried using your example, but my base class ```DBContext``` does not receive a string parameter in its constructor. This is a system class, not mine. I really appreciate your help

Comment: oh, sorry, did not realize you are on EFCore,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `SubmitChanges()` instead of `SaveChanges()`;

Comment: The ```SubmitChanges()``` method does not exist